# ReactJS Why is do I need static function in this code (Newbee)

Tags: reactjs, static

I am a newbie to react I cannot understand why the function "renderCategoryDiv" needs to be static.

What am I not getting right?

If I remove static the code won't work

My tools : Visual Studio 2020 .net Core 3 API, NodeJs, and react

My code looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; ...
export class Category extends Component {
    static displayName = Category.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { categories: [], ....

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateCategoryData();
    }



    static renderProductDiv(categories) {

        return (
            <Row>

          some code that works when the function is static

            </Row >


        );
    }

Then I have a async fetch of data
```

Comment: Where do you use `renderCategoryDiv`? Please add the code that's using it. I'm also not seeing the definition of that function or is it similar to `renderProductDiv`?

Comment: `Static properties are properties of a class, not of an instance of a class.` so your static members and function will belong to a class, not to an instance.

Comment: It was a fail 40, I did not understand the concept of => function. Now it works. Thanks for uour input